# Android : Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, socketexception

My app needs to retrieve compressed xml data from internet, here is how I get the inputstream :

```
URL feedUrl= new URL(url); 
inputStream = feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
```

But my problem is that I have an exception :

```
java.net.SocketException : Connection reset by peer
```

This exception is thrown only with my phone (but not when using wifi), it is not thrown with the emulator.
Anyone knows anything ? Thanks for helping

Comment: Same problem here. Neither URLConnection.getContentLength() nor URLConnection..getInputStream() work as I'd like them to when I use 3G network. I suspect the culprit is my mobile carrier, which must have blocked some types of HTTP traffic (I have difficulties downloading binary files from the android web browser too)